# module 'tensorflow.python.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist' has no attribute 'load_data'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am currently following this intro tutorial on the Keras website: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification

Several steps in I run into this error after calling `fashion_mnist.load_data()`:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist' has no attribute 'load_data'
```

This is the full output:

```
Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 27 2018, 03:37:03) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> from tensorflow import keras
>>> fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
>>> (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist' has no attribute 'load_data'
```

I'm using tensorflow `1.5.0`, Keras `2.2.2`, and Python `3.6.6`.

Is tensorflow's tutorial outdated, or am I missing something? If I use the `mnist` set instead of `fashion_mnist`, it works with no problem. From this link https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist it would seem that `fashion_mnist` does indeed have a function called `load_data`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem lies indeed in your Tensorflow version. The tutorial you [link to](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification) uses version 1.9.0:

```python
print(tf.__version__)
# 1.9.0
```

which does include a function `load_data` for `fashion_mnist` ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.9/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist)). But this function is missing from your version, as you can see from the [v1.5 docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.5/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
import tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras.datasets
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `keras.datasets.fashion_mnist` you can try to use `tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist`.

Comment: Please read the question more closely; before `keras.datasets.fashion_mnist` there is a `from tensorflow import keras` statement, so what is actually imported here is indeed `tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by reinstalling tensorflow using pip instead of conda